# C# DataGridView cell update not updating last row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a button which updates all values in column 3 (C) (except the header) with whatever has been selected in a combo box.

```
    private void updateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!RowIsEmpty(i))
            {
                dataGridView1[2, i].Value = Combo.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

**This works apart from it doesn't update the last row.**

RowIsEmpty:

```
    private bool RowIsEmpty(int rowIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[i].Value != null &&
                dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `dataGridView1[2, i]`???

Comment: @Rahul This is to update column C

Comment: `dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;` it is not skipping the last row?

Comment: @Mikev It is skipping the last row

Comment: So, if you wan't to update the last row, but you are skipping her.. Or am I confusing something?

Comment: @Mikev Are you saying I need to remove `-1` ?

Comment: @Matt I've build what i'm saying in an answer, check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `updateExcel_Click`..

The problem, in my point of view, is in this for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
```

Because you are jumping rows here so, imagine `dataGridView1.RowCount` have a value of 3, and you are making `dataGridView1.RowCount - 1` so `dataGridView1.RowCount = 2`.

With this your for will running 0, 1 and 2. When the objective, in my point of view, you wanna him to run 0, 1, 2 and 3.

The problem you saying on your question is: Not updating last row, because for is jumping the last row..

Solution:

```
private void updateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
   {
      if (!RowIsEmpty(i))
      {
          dataGridView1[2, i].Value = Combo.Text;
      }
   }
}
```

Or if you want to keep the logic you have, you need on your for, add this `<`, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
```